# Programatically Add RadTextBox to a RadListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, asp.net-ajax

I have three RadListBox controls on a page. When a user drags an item from the first listbox to the second listbox, I need the third one to automatically generate a textbox.

I've figured out how to add a regular HTML textbox with JavaScript. However, I'm not able to access this in the code behind page because adding a `runat=server` field causes an error. Here's the client JavaScript code I'm using to insert a textbox:

```
//Add textbox to 3rd listbox    
var listbox = $find("<%= ListBoxThree.ClientID %>");
listbox.trackChanges();
var textboxItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadListBoxItem();
textboxItem.set_text(item.get_text()); //sets the ID
textboxItem.set_clientTemplate("  <input id=\"#= Text #\" type=\"text\" /> ");
textboxItem.bindTemplate();
textboxItem.set_value
listbox.get_items().add(textboxItem);
listbox.commitChanges();
```

If I try adding `runat=server` I get the following error:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
Line 70:                     textboxItem.set_clientTemplate("  <input id=\"#= Text #\" type=\"text\" runat=\"server\" /> ");
```

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

When the user hits the Save button though, the item's Text and Value fields do not get updated with the text they've entered.

```
    protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (RadListBoxItem item in ListBoxThree.Items)
        {
            string value = item.Value;
            string text = item.Text;
        }
    }
```

If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: What is the 'runat=server' error?

Comment: I added the error message to my question. It seems like since I'm using javascript, asp.net isn't able to parse my tag. But I'm not sure how to do this without using javascript